# Multiple Microservice and their communication

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

I have microservices A,B,C,D up to Z.

Suppose that microservice A wants to communicate with rest of the microservices than how can we do this?

Comment: Take a look at `FeignClient`. If the microservices are routed using Zuul, you can use their aliases instead of fixed URLs.

Comment: Btw. the question is too broad. I don't understand what problems do you face. What keywords have you used for searching for the possible ways of implementation?

Comment: `rest of the microservices` what do you mean ? Talking with other microservices in any communication protocol  or only talking with them through REST api ?

Comment: are you like to process a REST call or are you looking for a service registry or something else? Is your app running in docker or some other high level container services like kubernetes or do you use Eureka as service registry?

Comment: @Sma Ma i am using REST.
But deployment part os not my concern.
Question is how can a single microservice connect with many services say 100 services.

Answer (score 0):

This guide walks you through the process of creating an application that consumes a RESTful web service.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

**What You Will Build:**

You will build an application that uses Spring’s RestTemplate to retrieve a random Spring Boot quotation at https://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random.

**Short description:**

Use RestTemplate to process a http rest call.

> RestTemplate is a synchronous client to perform HTTP requests,
>   exposing a simple, template method API over underlying HTTP client
>   libraries such as the JDK HttpURLConnection, Apache HttpComponents,
>   and others. The RestTemplate offers templates for common scenarios by
>   HTTP method, in addition to the generalized exchange and execute
>   methods that support of less frequent cases.

**Example from guide:**

```
package com.example.consumingrest;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ConsumingRestApplication {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConsumingRestApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConsumingRestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner run(RestTemplate restTemplate) throws Exception {
        return args -> {
            Quote quote = restTemplate.getForObject(
                    "https://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random", Quote.class);
            log.info(quote.toString());
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a service registry you can use Eureka:

**Service Registration and Discovery**

This guide walks you through the process of starting and using the Netflix Eureka service registry.

**What You Will Build**

You will set up a Netflix Eureka service registry and then build a client that both registers itself with the registry and uses it to resolve its own host. A service registry is useful because it enables client-side load-balancing and decouples service providers from consumers without the need for DNS.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/